# Login in Facebook using restfb API (Java)

Tags: java, facebook, facebook-login, restfb

```
    public void login() {
    String domain = "https://www.iscte.pt/";
    String appId = "27298787851280";
    String authUrl = "https://graph.facebook.com/oauth/authorize?type=user_agent&client_id="+appId+"&redirect_uri="+domain+"&scope=user_about_me,"
            + "user_actions.books,user_actions.fitness,user_actions.music,user_actions.news,user_actions.video,user_activities,user_birthday,user_education_history,"
            + "user_events,user_photos,user_friends,user_games_activity,user_groups,user_hometown,user_interests,user_likes,user_location,user_photos,user_relationship_details,"
            + "user_relationships,user_religion_politics,user_status,user_tagged_places,user_videos,user_website,user_work_history,ads_management,ads_read,email,"
            + "manage_notifications,manage_pages,publish_actions,read_friendlists,read_insights,read_mailbox,read_page_mailboxes,read_stream,rsvp_event";
    System.setProperty("webdirver.chrome.driver", "chromedriver.exe");

    WebDriver driver = new ChromeDriver();
    driver.get(authUrl);
    String accessToken;
    while(true){

        if(!driver.getCurrentUrl().contains("facebook.com")){
            String url = driver.getCurrentUrl();
            accessToken = url.replaceAll(".*#access_token=(.+)&.*", "$1");
            driver.quit();
        }

    }
}
```

I'm trying to get user's access token. I've already imported all libraries. Here's my code, but when I try to execute it, it shows this error:

https://i.stack.imgur.com/LhsXO.png

Answer (score 0):

You set the system property to "web*dirver*.chrome.driver" but it should be "web*driver*.chrome.driver".

It's just a little typo. Please try again with that change.